# How to get elapsed timed in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvm

I want my timer  to continue from the time I started it until now, I need help with the logic that uses timespan to calculate the elapsed time from the minutes the timer started  to the current time, Here is what I have done:

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = _cancellationTokenSource; // safe copy

       
          //Timer Starts here
         _TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(TimeSheet.TotalTime);
      

       //Increment timer by a second interval
        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () => {

            if (cts.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {

                     _TimeSpan += TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

                    displaytime = _TimeSpan.ToString(@"h\:m\:s");
                    TimeSheet.TotalTimeForDisplay = displaytime;

                    Console.WriteLine("Timer");
                    Console.WriteLine(displaytime);

                });

                return true;

            }
```

Comment: @Jason It seems the Stopwatch class doesn't havE parameters to Overide where the stop watch should start

Comment: I would use something of the System.Reactive toolbox instead. There are good observables there like Interval, Timeout etc.

Answer (score 1):

use `System.Timers.Timer`

```
// use whatever start time you need
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

// 1000ms = 1s
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);

timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;

timer.Start();
```

then

```
private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    var elapsed = DateTime.Now - start;
}
```

Comment: For my start timer I'm using   _TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(TimeSheet.TotalTime); of do I need to convert to DateTime?

Comment: I don't know.  You haven't described what your requirements are so I can't say what the right value to use is.